# Clear only one Latex Fragment in Emacs Org-mode

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

**Intro**: The function org-preview-latex-fragment either renders the latex in entire section OR only one latex fragment (if the point is in it). However, the clear (C-c C-c) always removes all the images.

**Q**: is there a way to remove only one image (the one pointed to)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-c C-x C-l runs `org-toggle-latex-fragment` and will toggle on/off the fragment that you are on at the time or with a prefix argument, all fragmens in the current subtree, or all fragments in the buffer. See the documentation of the function for more details.

Note that `org-preview-latex-fragment` is obsolete since org 8.3 and is just an alias to `org-toggle-latex-fragment`. Also note that C-c C-c does not do anything useful for fragments any longer: this is an attempt to reduce the overload that this particular key sequence currently carries.

Comment: I was wondering: did you try out the answer? Did it do what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I couldn't try it because I had an old version of org-mode and when I upgraded it caused unbearable stalls, so I reverted to the old version. I'm sure it will work once I upgrade it correctly.

Comment: OK - if you still have problems after you upgrade, we can revisit this.